# Error in dynamically allocating memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to calculate the determinant of an NxN matrix. This piece of code gives an error in lines where I try to allocate the memory dynamically.

> error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float *"
>
> error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float **"

```
double CalcDeterminant( float **mat, int order)
{
    float **minor;
    unsigned short i;
    float det = 0;
    // order must be >= 0
    // stop the recursion when matrix is a single element
    if( order == 1 )
        return mat[0][0];

    // the determinant value
    // allocate the cofactor matrix

    **minor = malloc((order-1) * sizeof(float *));
    for(i=0;i<order-1;i++)
        minor[i] = malloc((order-1) * sizeof(float));**

    //float *mat2d = malloc( rows * cols * sizeof( float ));
    for(i = 0; i < order; i++ )
    {
        // get minor of element (0,i)
        GetMinor( mat, minor, 0, i , order);
        // the recusion is here!

        det += (i%2==1?-1.0:1.0) * mat[0][i] * CalcDeterminant(minor,order-1);
        //det += pow( -1.0, i ) * mat[0][i] * CalcDeterminant( minor,order-1 );
    }

    // release memory
    for(i=0;i<order-1;i++)
        free(minor[i]);
    free(minor);
    return det;
}
```

Comment: @Tarun, please note that idiomatic English uses `I` rather than `i`, no spaces before periods (full stops), and capitalizes the first word of every sentence.

Comment: hey @sarnold, I lost the link to this particular question, hence it wasn't quite edited the way I would have wanted it to be. Also, you can have a look at my previous edits, wherein I've corrected such mistakes made by the user.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the line `#include <stdlib.h>` so that `malloc()` is properly declared.

As it stands, the compiler is being very lax (C89 mode) and allowing implicit function declarations, so when the compiler comes across `malloc()`, it assumes that it is a function that returns an `int`, instead of the correct `void *`.

You need to change your compilation options until the compiler complains more loudly.  For example, if you use GCC, you should consider:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes ...
```

You may prefer, or even need, to use `-std=gnu99` instead `-std=c99`; that enables many extensions while still using the C99 core language.  But using options along those lines and ensuring there are no compilation warnings is good discipline.  Using `-Werror` enforces the discipline; it converts any warning message from the compiler into an error, so the compilation fails.

Comment: This is why you don't cast the value from `malloc` in C (which Imran Afzal got right).

Comment: If you routinely compile with the stringent options, the cast does no harm in C and permits the code to be compiled by a C++ compiler (where the cast from `void *` is mandatory).  Whether that is sufficient reason for including the cast depends on your goals.

Comment: I used to use pretty much all the -W switches I could find back when I did C portability for a living. And I used the SINIX compiler as an extra strictness check (SINIX was German). And I made everyone remove the unnecessary casts. Every little bit helps when you're dealing with half a million lines of C, five developers, and ten platforms.

Comment: I recognize SINIX - Siemens-Nixdorf Unix.  And I remember dealing with 10 platforms, or more.  We're down to 6 now, lumping multiple flavours of Linux into 'one platform'.  If you count the variations on Linux, the number is considerably higher than just 6.  And, if I had my way, we'd be using more stringent `-Wxxxx` options - but the code is big enough and ancient enough (some dates back to about 1982) that it isn't feasible to do so - yet.  I'm working towards that goal...but slowly, oh so slowly.  (Only half a million lines; luxury!)

Comment: Half a million lines of C that was originally written for, ahem, DOS in the 1980s and then ported by David Tilbrook to a pile of Unixen. Most of the developers hated the SINIX compiler, I was pleased by its strictness. 1982? Luxury. I had to code outside in the snow on a SCO machine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the header file `stdlib.h`.